# $SO(3)$, orbital angular momentum, vector product

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, symmetry, group-theory, rotation

I have a big confusion with group theory terminology. I know that orbital angular momentum (OAM) is $\mathrm{SO}(3)$-symmetric in 3D-space. Let's define QM orbital angular momentum (OAM) conventionally:

$$\pmb{L} = -i \pmb{r} \times \pmb{\nabla}$$

This definition can also be written using a set of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ generators:

$$L^{\mu} = -i r_i \; S_{ij}^{\mu} \; \nabla_j$$

where $\mu = \{x,y,z\}$ for 3D space, and $S_{ij}^{\mu}$.

So... generators stand for the definition of a vector product in given space, essentially, definition of orthogonality? Or this is only in this case, I suppose, in which case why such a coincidence?

---

If I proceed with this:

$$\pmb{r} e^{-iS^{\mu} \phi} \pmb{p}= \pmb{r} \cdot \pmb{p} - i \delta \phi \; \pmb{r} S^{\mu} \pmb{p} + \cdots = \mathrm{const} \; e^{- i \pmb{r} \cdot \pmb{p}} + \delta \phi L^{\mu}$$

Matter wave in zeroth order and OAM in first? Does it have any interpretation?

Comment: A generic element $g$ of a continuous group would be $g=e^{i \mathbf{T}_i \theta_i}$ where $\mathbf{T}_i$ are infinitesimal generators of the group, and $\theta_i$ is a real parameter.

Comment: **Where are the elements and where is the operation here?** Admittedly, I'm pretty stupid, but it's unclear to me if you are referring to **all** possible orbital densities under (SO(3)) or the spherical ones alone?

Comment: @StudyStudyStudy , honestly, I have no idea what you are talking about. I took Arfken&Weber and read the Group Theory Chapter, literally. I think I got that question though. Now, next question is why the action of group generators end up being identical to vector product operation, that I don't get.

Comment: So, generators of group representation is/can be an operation?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I've understood your question well. The math may be too complicated for me, but the ideas are

1. The usual definition of OAM satisfies the conmutation rule

$$\left[\frac{L_x}{\hbar}, \frac{L_y}{\hbar}\right]=i \frac{L_z}{\hbar}$$

2. This means that they are infinitesimal generators of rotations in the space they live in.

   3. And that's correct: in fact  $\exp(-i\theta L_n/\hbar)$ is actually the "rotation" operator of an angle $\theta$ about an axis $n$  in Hilbert's space.

You can prove this by stablishing

$$ \varphi_F (\vec{x}) = \varphi_0(R^{-1}\vec{x})$$

Which means "the updated wavefunction in any point is equal to the *old* wavefunction evaluated in the point before the rotation".

$R$ is the rotation matrix in $\mathbb{R}^3$.